# Selenium find element with class and style visibility

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a element using its class name but just be sure i also would like to check if the element is visible below is the code.

`1. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'" +Search.SearchType+ "') and contains(@style, '" +visibility: visible+ "')] /div/div[contains(text(),'Find Insured')]")).click();`

`2. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'" +Search.SearchType+ "') and contains(@visibility, 'visible')] /div/div[contains(text(),'Find Insured')]")).click();`

1. Syntax error on visibility
2. unable to locate element exception
   When I remove the "and contains(@visibility, 'visible')" part it works fine

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are trying to locate?  Also, on your first statement, change the `'" +visibility: visible+ "'` to `'visibility: visible'`...that's your syntax error

Comment: Great!! it worked after correcting the syntax error

Answer (score 4):

@Brantley: Selenium's `isDisplayed()` api is just for this purpose, to check visibility of element by not having to parse the 'style' attribute.

[Check here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
By.cssSelector("div." + Search.SearchType + ":not([style *= 'display:none'])")
```

Comment: This did not work throws a exception No such element found. I would take the correction above given by MrTi Thanks