# java selenium how to find a div element which has got style='display: block'

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to automation testing.

Can anyone tell how to find div element which has got style property display: block;? I tried below but not working

```
WebElement addedDiv = frm.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@style,'display: block']"));
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share html code

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359237/selenium-find-element-with-class-and-style-visibility

Comment: @MukilDeepthi 99% elements on a page will have `style` property set to `display: block;`. It won't be an efficient way. Try other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You can do

```
//button[@style='display: block']
```

if it's an exact match or

```
//button[contains(@style,'display: block')]
```

if you want a partial match.

NOTE: I don't know the full HTML since you haven't posted it but this may not be the best way to locate this element. The `display` attribute may change, depending on the page, etc.